# Unable to extract a value from json and use it in subsequent request

Tags: jmeter-5.0

My test receives the following `json` in response.

```
{"result":"success","additional-info":"{\"q-list\":[{\"tag\":\"un2-new tag2-empty\",\"description\":\"some description2\",\"q-id\":\"5c86fb8a-d9ce-4978-be4c-2c4b547c7868\",\"creation-year\":2020,\"creation-month\":11,\"creation-hour\":8,\"creation-minute\":48}],\"pagination-info\":{\"page-state\":\"004400100038000800000000000000080800000000000000302435633836666238612d643963652d343937382d626534632d326334623534376337383638f07ffffffef07ffffffe9fde9512dc65b09db4b903cca66a71aa0004\",\"partition-info\":{\"year\":2020,\"month\":11}}}"}
```

I want to extract `q-id` from the response and the use it in next request. I have created the following extractor.

[image]

and am using it as follows:

[image]

But I see that the value is not getting extracted.

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Happy to accept other answers. I was able to solve the issue by using `beanshell` script. However, I still don't know why extracting value from `Regular Expression Extractor` didn't work.

Beanshell script

```
import com.eclipsesource.json.*;

//prev.setSuccessful(false);
try {
    String jsonString = prev.getResponseDataAsString(); //response as string
    log.info("received json string: "+jsonString);
    
    JsonObject responseAsJsonObject = JsonObject.readFrom(jsonString); //convert response string as json
    log.info("converted to object: "+responseAsJsonObject);
    
    String additionalInfoString = responseAsJsonObject.get("additional-info").asString(); //get additional info string from json object
    log.info("additional info as string: "+additionalInfoString);
    
    JsonObject additionalInfoJsonObject = JsonObject.readFrom(additionalInfoString); //convert additional info string to json
    log.info("additional info as object: "+additionalInfoJsonObject);
    
    JsonArray questionListObject = additionalInfoJsonObject.get("questions-list").asArray(); //get questions list array
    log.info("questions list: "+questionListObject );
    
    JsonObject firstQuestionFromList = questionListObject.get(0).asObject(); //get 1st question
    log.info("first question: "+firstQuestionFromList);
    
    String questionID = firstQuestionFromList.get("question-id").asString();
    log.info("question id of 1st question "+questionID);
    vars.put("questionIDFromBeanShell",questionID); //use this in next request
//  prev.setSuccessful(true);
} catch (Exception e){
    log.info("error in processing beanshell script: ", e);
    prev.setSuccessful(false);
}
```

[image]